# Is there a simple way of refactoring this code?

Tags: c++, algorithm, templates, refactoring, std

I have a function that have very similar repeating code. I like to refactor it, but don't want any complex mapping code.

The code basically filter out columns in a table.  I made this example simple by having the comparison statement having a simple type, but the real comparison can be more complex.

I am hoping there may be some template or lambda technique that can do this.

```
vector<MyRecord*>& MyDb::Find(bool* field1, std::string * field2, int* field3)
{
    std::vector<MyRecord*>::iterator iter;
    filterList_.clear();
    std::copy(list_.begin(), list_.end(), back_inserter(filterList_));

    if (field1)
    {
        iter = filterList_.begin();
        while (iter != filterList_.end())
        {
            MyRecord* rec = *iter;
            if (rec->field1 != *field1)
            {
                filterList_.erase(iter);
                continue;
            }
            iter++;
        }
    }

    if (field2)
    {
        iter = filterList_.begin();
        while (iter != filterList_.end())
        {
            MyRecord* rec = *iter;

            if (rec->field2 != *field2)
            {
                filterList_.erase(iter);
                continue;
            }
            iter++;
        }
    }

    if (field3)
    {
        iter = filterList_.begin();
        while (iter != filterList_.end())
        {
            MyRecord* rec = *iter;

            if (rec->field3 != *field3)
            {
                filterList_.erase(iter);
                continue;
            }
            iter++;
        }
    }
    return filterList_;
}
```

---

**Update**: Just in case someone is curious, this is my final code.  Thanks again everyone.  A lot easy to understand and maintain.

```
vector<MyRecord*>& MyDb::Find(bool* field1, std::string* field2, int* field3)
{
    auto compare = [&](MyRecord* rec) {
        bool add = true;
        if (field1 && rec->field1 != *field1) {
            add = false;
        }
        if (field2 && rec->field2 != *field2) {
            add = false;
        }
        if (field3 && rec->field3 != *field3) {
            add = false;
        }
        return add;
    };

    filterList_.clear();

    std::copy_if(list_.begin(), list_.end(), back_inserter(filterList_), compare);
    return filterList_;
}
```

Comment: `if ((field1 && rec->field1 != *field1)) || (field2 && rec->field2 != *field2) || (field3 && rec->field3 != *field3) { ...}`. Drop `if (field1)` and other checks up front, run the loop once, checking for all three fields at once.

Comment: just suggestion - instead of creation of full copy and then erasing elements, I'd copy only needed elements from original list into filtered one

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Like I said I made this example simple, the real code has a few more columns and different data type than this.  I want to avoid having a giant if statement. I might end up doing it anyway.

Comment: If templates/lambda fails, you can always resort to using macros

Comment: I believe so.  All the columns are optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple way of refactoring this code?

As far as I understood your algorithm/ intention, using [`std::erase_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/erase2) ([c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20)) you can replace the entire while loops as follows ([Demo code](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/WY6nEjdEE)):

```
#include <vector> // std::erase_if

std::vector<MyRecord*> // return by copy as filterList_ is local to function scope
Find(bool* field1 = nullptr, std::string* field2 = nullptr, int* field3 = nullptr)
{
    std::vector<MyRecord*> filterList_{ list_ }; // copy of original
    const auto erased = std::erase_if(filterList_, [=](MyRecord* record) { 
        return record 
            && ((field1 && record->field1 != *field1)
            || (field2 && record->field2 != *field2)
            || (field3 && record->field3 != *field3));
        }
    );
    return filterList_;
}
```

---

If no support for C++20, alternatively you can use [erase–remove idiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase%E2%80%93remove_idiom), which is in effect happening under the hood of `std::erase_if`.

Comment: Thanks JeJo and everyone else.   I think your answer is the most relevant answer to what I looking for.  I will make a slight change.  I will use find_if and add to the list instead of removing.

Comment: @tadpole I think the other answer is more you want, as you work with a copy.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`std::copy_if`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) (as you already/would do a copy anyway)

```cpp
vector<MyRecord*>& MyDb::Find(bool* field1, std::string* field2, int* field3){
  filterList_.clear();
  std::copy_if(list_.begin(), list_.end(), back_inserter(filterList_),[&](MyRecord* rec){
    // whatever condition you want.
    return field3 && rec->field3 != *field3;
  });
  return filterList_;
}
```